# С++. Как найти ближайший к 10 элемент в массиве?

Tags: c++, массивы

Функция также должна вернуть через параметры номер и значение элемента массива, который ближе всего расположен к значению 10.

```
if (abs(10-abs(a[i])) < abs(min)) {
            min = a[i];
            n = i;
        }
```

Попробовала вот эту штуку, но не как. Подскажите что делать.

Answer (score 3):

Если воспользоваться стандартным алгоритмом `min_element`, то это делается буквально в одну строку:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 18, 4, 9, 44, -2, 1 };
    auto it = min_element(a,a+size(a),[](int x, int y){return abs(x-10) < abs(y-10);});
    cout << *it << " at pos " << (it - a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего оставить модуль (`abs`) для разности между 10 и проверяемым элементом массива. Сам элемент, как и минимум, в модуль возводить не надо — тогда код будет некорректно себя вести при тестах типа `-9 4`.

Comment: не работает, если за минимум брать первый элемент массива.

Comment: А Вы проинициализировали минимум как достаточно крупное число (10^9)?

Answer (score 0):

Все прносто возьмите разницу по модулю занчения массива и искомого и ищите пока не найдете минимум т.е 0 если значение есть или дельту с ним  - т.е. самое ближайшее

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>

constexpr std::size_t size{25};
constexpr int start_val{-12};

int main()
{
    // генерация  данных
    std::array<int, size> arr;
    std::iota(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), start_val);

    //сам алгоритм
    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); // установим максимальное значение
    int magic{10};
    int min_val{0};
    std::size_t pos{0};

    for (std::size_t i{0}; i < arr.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto tmp = std::abs(arr[i] - magic);
        if (tmp < min)
        {
            min = tmp;
            min_val = arr[i];
            pos = i;
        }
    }

    std::cout << min_val << " at " << pos << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```